# Nodejs server not visible on lan

Tags: node.js, server, centos7

I have installed a fresh CentOS 7 on my server and now I would like to run a nodejs server, but there is some problem I can't figure out. What I have is a simple nodejs server:
`hello.js`

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/');
```

I have tried with `.listen(8080);` also `.listen(80);` no success with those as well.

The strange thing is that, I can access the server locally with `curl localhost:8080` it works as expected. But when I try from another machine on the same network it doesn't work.
E.g.
The server ip is `192.168.2.136` when I try in my browser `192.168.2.136:8080` I get `192.168.2.136 refused to connect.`

Just to clarify that I have setup my modem with `DMZ` to my server ip.

Here is also netstat -ntl output

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

If someone can help with this would be great! thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your server's firewall configuration?

Comment: ty, u r right. It was the firewall. I had to add `firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp`. Ty again for the clue, I am not very good with the servers :)